# Use component inside mat-table

Tags: angular, angular-material

So, here's the issue:

I have a mat-table with 87 columns.  The data it displays can have several status, depending on the status, the data will be displayed in different subscreens, but all are in the same component, the issue is that each subset of data uses the same table specification.  So I end up with a template which duplicates all 87 fields 3 times (1 per status) and Sonar hates this

I can't find a way to do something like this:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceStatus1" class="head-table">
      <app-my-comp [dataSource]="dataSourceStatus1"></app-my-comp>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnId"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnId" class="row-tables"></tr>
 </table>
```

Where app-my-comp is a component like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-comp',
    templateUrl: './my.html',
    styleUrls: ['./style-my-style.component.scss'],
})

export class MyComponent {

    @Input() dataSource: Status1Data[];

}
```

And the html is the aforementioned 87 fields:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="field1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>field 1</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let let1">
        {{ myObject.someList.field1 }}
    </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="field2">

...
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Could not find column with id "field1"
```

Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftmcr4?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: Some of your Columns do not match with the rows, this is why you get this error.

Comment: Also, check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-tables?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi George, no, the columns are fine, the verbose template has been in use for several months, it's just now I'm doing a refactor to avoid duplication in Sonar, but when I try to split it and abstract the code to a separate component it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, Steven can you reproduce a small amount of your code in a stackblitz example so I will try to help you. Thanks

Comment: Why not using a ngFor loop to include the fields?

Comment: Hi George, have done a Stackblitz to ilustrate what I want to achieve, have forked Mat-Table's official stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftmcr4?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: @GCSDC Because it would end up being as verbose as declaring all columns in html, we have to set the naming manually for each column, as they're different from the DB, we also have special conditions (clickable, etc.) depending on values in each column, and so on, we would end up with the same amount of boilerplate as each section has its own particularities